# Hyphenopoly выдает ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, hyphenopoly

Вот такую ошибку я получаю:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.entries (<anonymous>)
    at Hyphenopoly.js:153:11
    at Hyphenopoly.js:209:7
    at Hyphenopoly.js:933:3
```

Код, который я использую для Hyphenopoly никак не влияет на ошибку. Пробовал его вырезать, ошибка все равно остается. Соответсвенно ошибку нужно искать в другом месте.

Все файлы подключил:

```
<script type="module" src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/hyphenopoly.module.js"></script>
<script src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/Hyphenopoly_Loader.js"></script>
<script src="/Hyphenopoly-5.0.0/Hyphenopoly.js"></script>
```